# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list can't seem to find possible solution

Tags: node.js, ejs

What is the issue, Where did I go wrong? This is the code for index.ejs i made minor changes to my previous old_index.ejs. i have been struggling with this issue and the backend does have await function for calling aleph-js (aleph.im) so i don't think it's any issue about async.

```
**strong text**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 rooms-sidebar">
                <div class="card no-outline">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <small>Logged in as</small><br>
                        <b>
                            hook this up later<br>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <hr>
                <div class="card no-outline mb-2 room-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span class='name'>
                            Chat
                        </span><br>
                        <span class='member-count'>
                            <small>
                                99 Members
                            </small>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="chat-room">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                        <span class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <b>
                                Chat
                            </b>
                        </span>
                        <small>
                            99 Members
                        </small>
                    </nav>
                    <div id="messages">
                        <% posts.forEach((post)=> { %>
                            <% var parsed_item=JSON.parse(post.item_content) %>
                            <div class="message mb-2">
                                <div class="content-container">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <%= parsed_item.content.body %>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="author">
                                        <%= parsed_item.address %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% }) %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-box">
                        <form action="/messages" method="post" id='message-form'>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type='text' name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">
                                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Post Message" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= posts %>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(() => {

                const socket = new WebSocket('wss://api2.aleph.im/api/ws0/messages?msgType=POST&contentType=chat')
                socket.onmessage = (e) => {
                    let message = JSON.parse(e.data)
                    console.log(message)
                    let content = message.content.content.body;
                    $('#messages-list').prepend(`<li>${content}</li>`)
                }
                $('#message-form').submit((e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post('/messages', $('#message-form').serialize())
                    $('#message-form textarea').val('')
                })
            })
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

<%= 'me' if message.user == current_user %>

[Refer The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BFKY.png)

Comment: Are you using git? Just take a diff to previous version and see what you changed

Comment: i checked everything and i cant seem to find any syntax error vs would've highlighted it , what's with async? i did use await in backend